# Select no Entity Framework de uma tabela resultante de um relacionamento N para N

Tags: entity-framework, dbset

Não sei se está muito clara a pergunta, então vou tentar ilustrar melhor o cenário.

Criei uma tabela de Atividades e uma de Usuários, na tabela de Atividades tenho um responsável pela mesma e posso ter também alguns usuários associados a esta.

No mapeamento coloquei esse relacionamento e deixei explicito que deveria ser criada uma nova tabela com o nome X e as propriedades *AtividadeID* e *UsuarioID*, por exemplo, como era de se esperar a tabela no banco foi criada normalmente e todos os relacionamentos estão funcionando, mas apareceu uma dúvida quando surgiu a necessidade de selecionar as atividades ao qual o usuário X está associado, não consigo fazer este select.

Preciso criar o *DBSet* desta tabela para conseguir fazer isto ou existe outra forma? Não criei ainda, pois não vi a necessidade já que consiga incluir, alterar e excluir normalmente os usuários associados.